# How can I enforce scaled mode on iPhone 6+ but not iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like the app to use an adjusted layout for iPhone 6, taking advantage of auto-layout etc. but then on iPhone 6+, use a scaled version of the app from iPhone 6. I tried only setting a launch image for iPhone 6 on the LaunchImage asset catalog, but it still runs on iPhone 6+ using its own layout, and not in scaled mode.

The reason I am trying to do this is that the app has a lot of empty space because of the large screen size, and it looks better with iPhone6 layout scaled up. The hard way to do it will be to work on the UI to make it take advantage of the extra pixels, but I thought as an initial step, a scaled-up version on iPhone 6+ would be nicer than what we can get with auto-layout and co. But maybe this is not a good idea anyway.